# Difference Between "Meist" and "Am Meisten"

Tags: grammar, word-usage, difference

My dictionary shows that *meist* and *am meisten* have similar meanings: most/mostly and related words.

What are the rules, if any, as to when either word should be used?

> Ich höre meist Lieder von Rammstein.
>
> Ich höre am meisten Lieder von Rammstein.

Which is right, are they both right, are they both wrong, etc.?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Meist*, *meistens* and *am meisten* can have the same meaning: In the sentence of your post you may hear all three. *Meistens* will probably be the most frequent word, then *am meisten*, *meist*, the shortened form of *meistens* will be not so frequent.

In a sentence like

> Was ich am meisten hasse, ist, wenn er mich betrügt.

you can only use *am meisten* meaning *in the highest degree*. And there is

> Die meisten Schulkinder lernen heute English als erste Fremdsprache. (Most children ...)

Comment: Maybe *Meist, meistens* and *am meisten* can have the same meaning  but as @frlan pointed out they have different meaning in the OP.

Comment: Yepp.... it really depends on the context here -- Unfortunately. But don't be alarmed: Most of the German speakers don't see the differences at all.

Comment: Good point, @frlan  This should be added to this answer for completeness.

Answer (score 4):

Very similar, but slightly differing meaning:

`Ich höre meist Lieder von Rammstein.` means something like "Most of the time I listen to songs of Rammstein" -- whereas `Ich höre am meisten Lieder von Rammstein.` means something like "Rammstein is my favorite band -- It's the band I'm listening to most". So the second meaning is it's used as a comparative degree comparing to other bands.

Answer (score 1):

Betrachten wir London, Paris und Belin, so regnet es in London am meisten.

"Es regnet in London meist" würde aber bedeuten, dass es dort häufiger regnet als nicht - ist also wohl eine Übertreibung. Meist nieselt es nur und ist neblig.